# Firebase Database RecyclerAdapter. How to filter data using specific field value of array?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have the next structure of Firebase Databese and I need select all models which has specific color value (e.g. "blue") in **colors** block.

[image]

Will it make possible using [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) with selection from database directly? Or it is possible only with filter on client-side such as:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    items.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Wallpaper wallpaper = postSnapshot.getValue(Wallpaper.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < wallpaper.getColors().size(); i++) {
            if (wallpaper.getColors().get(i).equals(filterValue)){
                items.add(wallpaper);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Thank's!